# SWT Table Resize, once column value and Table Max size reaches

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to add a big big string in a SWT table.
If you put any big String very long, then that column occupies the entire area and next columns are not even visible and you are left with no option.
Ideally that much max value should not be shown or some mechanism should be there to handle.

Here is the SWT table with normal view-
We can see 5 columns .

[image]

Now I modified Column 2 with a very long String and now we can see only 3 columns and rest of the columns are not even visible.

[image]

Following is the source code for the same.
I want to know how can I avoid this resizing problem if the content of the column is very long.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Snippet181 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK);
        table.setLayoutData(new RowData(-1, 300));
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
        column.setText("Column 0");
        column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
        column.setText("Column 1");
        column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
        column.setText("Column 2");
        column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
        column.setText("Column 3");
        column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
        column.setText("Column 4");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            String[] text=null;
            if(i >50 && i <55)
            text = new String[]{i+" 0", i+" 1", i+"282347378237895728975894758934895893458934789345834895792823473782378957289758947589348958934589347893458348957928234737823789572897589475893489589345893478934583489579282347378237895728975894758934895893458934789345834895792823473782378957289758947589348958934589347893458348957928234737823789572897589475893489589345893478934583489579282347378237895728975894758934895893458934789345834895792823473782378957289758947589348958934589347893458348957928234737823789572897589475893489589345893478934583489579282347378237895728975894758934895893458934789345834895792823473782378957289758947589348958934589347893458348957928234737823789572897589475893489589345893478934583489579282347378237895728975894758934895893458934789345834895792823473782378957289758947589348958934589347893458348957928234737823789572897589475893489589345893478934583489579", i+" 3", i+" 4"};
            else
                text = new String[]{i+" 0", i+" 1", i+" 282347", i+" 3", i+" 4"};
            item.setText(text);
        }
        Listener listener = new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                System.out.println("Move "+e.widget);
            }
        };
        TableColumn[] columns = table.getColumns();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            columns[i].pack();
            columns[i].setMoveable(true);
            columns[i].addListener(SWT.Move, listener);
        }
        Button b = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("invert column order");
        b.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                int[] order = table.getColumnOrder();
                for (int i = 0; i < order.length / 2; i++) {
                    int temp = order[i];
                    order[i] = order[order.length - i - 1];
                    order[order.length - i - 1] = temp;
                }
                table.setColumnOrder(order);
            }
        });
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the whole information of a single tableColumn necessary to be showed?If not,try to avoid it with a shorter string.Such as `text = longString.substring(0, 5) + "...";`

Comment: yes , I want to .. and if not atleast once I copy the column data , it should give me all the contents atleast , visually anything is fine

Comment: I run your code and I'm working under a screen resolution of 1920x1080,it's fine and I can see the whole 5 colunms.

Comment: if(i>50 $4 i<50) remove that condition and make setText for all the rows of the column

Comment: columns[i].pack(); is an issue...it will reset column size to preferred size ( total length of the cell label). you might want to set preferred width to column using setWidth() depending on your layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, using a `TableViewer` would make your life much easier.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html) is an excellent tutorial on `TableViewer`s.

I created an example that should give you an idea on how to accomplish what you want to do:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell);

    /* Create the columns */
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        /* Set the trim label provider (will trim the text displayed) */
        column.setLabelProvider(new TrimLabelProvider());
        column.getColumn().setText("Column " + i);
    }

    /* Set the input from the content provider */
    viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    viewer.setInput(DataModelProvider.getInstance().getItems());

    /* Style the table */
    Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    /* Pack the columns */
    for (TableColumn column : table.getColumns())
        column.pack();

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

/**
 * This class holds the data displayed in the table viewer
 */
private static class DataModelProvider
{
    private static DataModelProvider    INSTANCE;
    private List<TableRow>              items;

    public static DataModelProvider getInstance()
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new DataModelProvider();

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private DataModelProvider()
    {
        /*
         * Create dummy content. One item with short text and one item with
         * long text
         */
        items = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
        items.add(new TableRow(new String[] { "first", "second", "third", "fourth" }));
        items.add(new TableRow(new String[] { "first", "second second second second second second second second", "third", "fourth" }));
    }

    public void addItem(TableRow item)
    {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public List<TableRow> getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }
}

/**
 * This class models the data items displayed in the table
 */
private static class TableRow
{
    private String[]    data;

    public TableRow(String[] input)
    {
        data = input;
    }

    public String getData(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > data.length - 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index: " + index + ". Minimum: 0, Maximum: " + (data.length - 1));
        return data[index];
    }
}

/**
 * This class takes care of how the data is displayed in the table
 */
private static class TrimLabelProvider extends CellLabelProvider
{

    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell)
    {
        /*
         * This method is called by the TableViewer to get
         * the String to display in the cell
         */
        Object element = cell.getElement();
        if (element instanceof TableRow)
        {
            int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

            TableRow row = (TableRow) cell.getElement();

            /* Here we trim the text */
            cell.setText(shortenText(row.getData(columnIndex)));
        }
    }

    private String shortenText(String text)
    {
        /* This is the maximal length we allow */
        int value = 20;

        if (text.length() > value)
        {
            int index = text.indexOf(" ", value);
            if (index != -1)
                return text.substring(0, index) + " [...]";
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. The almost same logic I wrote for SWT.RESIZE listener only problem I am facing is that I have a Right click menu to copy the content of column, as now this value has been trimmed , while copying I lost data , only option left with me is to store the original data to some storage but what if the number of rows grows and all column data are random , then storage size will impact

Comment: @bunta The untrimmed data is still contained in the `DataModelProvider`. You add or delete items from this provider if you want to add or delete to the table viewer. Similarly, if you want to get the untrimmed String, get it from the provider.